# How to create a new index entry using imakeidx package?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, xindy

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF THE FOLLOWING ANSWERS!**

1. [Makeindex cannot generate subsubsub.. index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198094/makeindex-cannot-generate-subsubsub-index-entries)
2. [How to Permit 4-Level Deep Index Entries (was, "Why are Index Entries Rejected?"}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657397/how-to-permit-4-level-deep-index-entries-was-why-are-index-entries-rejected)
3. [Creating an index with sub-sub-subentries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/creating-an-index-with-sub-sub-subentries)

I am writing an index using imakeidx package and I require of additional level into index: I tried to implement or use the solutions into the above linked answers but they do not work strangely so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask a solution pointing out the following items:

- I have to compile with XelaTeX or LualaTeX since I uploaded fontspec package;
- I use TeXstudio;
- I tried to switch to texindy executable without successful;
- I require the index must be divided (as into a dictionary) into "alphabetical" sections ordered by usual lexicographic (alphabetical) order.

So I tried to use the code below which use markup command but it does not work since it does not print the following nested sequence.

```
\index{Animal! Mammals! Primates! Humans}
```

Could someone help me, please?

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{index_style.ist}
    headings_flag 1
    
    (markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
    
    (markup-index :open  "~n\begin{theindex}~n"
        :close "~n\end{theindex}~n"
    :tree
    )
    (markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{0} \item "            :depth 0)
    (markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{1}     \subitem "      :depth 1)
    (markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{2}       \subsubitem " :depth 2)
    (markup-indexentry :open "~n \def\tedLevel{3}           \subsubsubitem " :depth 3)
    
    heading_prefix "\n\\large\\bfseries
    
    \\normalfont\\noindent\\textbf{"heading_suffix "}\\par\\nopagebreak\n"
    
    item_0 "\n \\item \\normalsize "
    
    delim_0 " \\dotfill "
    delim_1 " \\dotfill "
    delim_2 " \\dotfill "
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subsubsubitem}{\@idxitem\hspace*{40\p@}}
\makeatother

\makeindex[title = Analytical index, columns = 2, columnseprule = true, options = -s index_style.ist, intoc = true]


\begin{document}
    This is a Texts.
    
    \index{Animal}
    \index{Animal!Mammals}
    \index{Animal!Mammals!Primates}
    \index{Animal!Mammals!Primates!Humans}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

**N.B.**

If you need, [here](https://mega.nz/file/AiNWgDqB#vgGSk7bkM1rX_fDi3etZ-dyXUVvazD12vfAKmXuO2XE) you can see my complete preamble.

Comment: Do not show lots of small snippets make a small, complete example. Remove all irrelevant packages (like skak or bbding and others).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just edited the question: I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: that is still not a complete example that one can compile.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I put a complete executable code putting at the end a mega-link where it is possibile to download my complete preamble, provided you need it:  I hope now the question it is complete; forgive my previous roughness.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro, you probably can reduce your MWE to 10-20 lines of code ... For guidance, kindly run through this checklis: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Please remove all those distracting thingies we really don't need to understand, reproduce and solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: @MS-SPO I think now I deleted all unnecessary packages to run the code, fontspec included. Forgive  for my mistake: I hope now the code is more readble. Thanks for the linked rulebook!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro, thank you, code-wise this looks better now. // However, why do you touch index_style.ist at all?

Comment: @MS-SPO If you refer to the extension I can say that I originally used makeindex program and this is my "original" code: however using xindy and so .xdy extesion nothing changes unfortunately.